# Bash shell script to input 2 integers. the second must be larger than the first

Tags: bash, shell

This is I'm pretty sure, way off. but here goes.

```
echo "Enter a number:"
read number

if ["$number" = 0] 
    echo "Enter the second, larger, number:"
read second_number

if ["$second_number" < "$number"]
     then 
     echo "Second number must be larger than the first number"
else

if ["$second_number" > "$number"]
     then
     echo "Good Job!"
fi
```

I realize this is probably riddled with mistakes.  That being said you can probably assume that I have no idea what I'm doing and you'd be right.

For the third line the `= 0` part is wrong i dont know how to ask for a numerical input

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider explain what is the problem you're facing. It's not enough with your code if we don't understand what is your problem. Also use **{}** button to properly format your code.

Comment: I would test if something is an integer with this pattern: `[[ $i != *[^[:digit:]]* ]]`.

Answer (score 1):

this is an excellent guide to programming the bash shell [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html) and for the tests look at the menu item [Reference Cards](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#REFCARDS)

To specifically answer your question the correct form of the if statement for testing numeric arguments is

```
if [ $number -eq 0 ]
then
    # do something
fi
```

Comment: if the contents of $number has a space in it then it is not an integer and will be treated as a string, thus the test will fail as -eq/-lt/-gt etc are specific integer tests.

Comment: Yes, in this sense the behavior is correct, although the `-bash: [: too many arguments` error message may not be desirable behavior and is easily prevented with quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter a number:"
read number

if [ "$number" -eq 0 ]
then
        echo "Enter the second, larger, number:"
        read second_number

        if [ "$second_number" -gt "$number" ]
        then
                echo "Good Job!"
        else
                echo "Second number must be larger than the first number"
        fi
fi
```